# Automatically Match the Height of the Box on the Left

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not really sure if this can be done using pure CSS, or does it need jQuery? anyway, I want the boxes to be the same height on each sides, so if the content on the right is longer than the left, the left will follow the height of the right box.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4ukj/)

My CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
}
.box {
    width:100px;
    background: #ccc;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.box:nth-child(2n+0) {
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Remove `width:100px;` http://jsfiddle.net/L4ukj/1/

Comment: and what would be the result then..??

Comment: @vinex: http://jsfiddle.net/L4ukj/3/ check this

Comment: @ling.s i guess you didnt get my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:table`

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4ukj/3)

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    display:table;
}
.box {
    width:100px;
    background: #ccc;
   /* float:left;*/
    display:table-cell;
   border: 10px solid #fff;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: I ddnt notice that you have added class row in HTML. In the PHP file im working that is not possible,

Comment: `display:table` will not work without `display:row` in your case

Comment: can you fix it without adding anything to the HTML?